# Increase Oracle XE table space

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I have installed Oracle XE but as we know XE having some limited size table space which we can use after that we not even create record in table.
So there is any why we can increase table space in Windows machine.

Comment: If this is a clean install and thus below the hard 11G limit, perhaps you simply need to grant quota to your users? If you have reached the limit you are out of luck and it is time to pay Oracle for standard edition. Or get rid of some old data if that is possible.